# Microsoft Test Manager 2010 Error: The required category 'Microsoft.TestCaseCategory' does not exist in team project

Tags: testing, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

When I'm attempting to open any of our projects in TFS 2010 with Microsoft Test Manager 2010, I get the error: **The required category 'Microsoft.TestCaseCategory' does not exist for project XXXXXXX**.

What is the reason for this error, and what steps can I take to resolve it?

*Also, is stackoverflow the right forum for this question? I feel like it's not really a programming question, but it didn't seem to have an obvious home to me*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely you used either a 3rd party template or a template included in a prior version of TFS.  Was this TFS server upgraded from 2005 or 2008 to 2010?  Here is some information on applying the categories to an older or unsupported process template: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/12/15/how-can-i-configure-mtlm-to-use-my-custom-bug-test-case-type.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this? [not supported](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=229062) Looks like the posting was from a couple of days ago as well.

Comment: That's specific to TFS projects on CodePlex - we have our own TFS instance.

Comment: Did you check the work item they entered? Some scripts to run, etc...to fix the issue on that end. May work for you. http://codeplex.codeplex.com/workitem/25567

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best and most detailed article I have found that walks you step by step through how to import the relevant Work Item Types and Category definitions:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lakhminder/archive/2010/09/30/tfs-2010-enable-test-case-management-for-upgraded-team-projects.aspx